# Kubernetes CPU/RAM Reservation for Pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there a means in Kubernetes to define reserve CPU and RAM for pods to use for bursting?

With the assumption that my pods will not peak at the same time, I could identify CPU and RAM they would require when few of them burst. `request` field is too wasteful if nominal utilisation is 20% of the request and `limit` field is not guaranteed. Addressing the requirement using QOS is not perfect.

Example, I want to be able to guarantee like 1CPU and 4GB RAM as common legroom for all the pods in my specific nodegroup. I don't want Kubernetes to allocate even the smallest allocation request like 0.1 CPU/2MB RAM. I want it really reserved for bursting use of the already running pods. Not for system reservation.

Comment: Can you clarify the behavior you want a little bit more?  Are you trying to keep some unallocated memory on each node above and beyond the scheduled pods' resource requests, just in case?

Comment: Yeah I am a bit confused. "reserved for bursting" is a bit of an oxymoron :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you might be interested in [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#vertical-pod-autoscaler).